# How can I run some custom javascript whenever a notebook is opened in VSCode?

Tags: webview, vscode-extensions

I am trying to write a VSCode extension that adds a mutation observer to a notebook webview in VSCode. I don't see a way to get hold of the current webview in VSCode, are there any workarounds?

I have gone over the documentation and it appears there isn't any way to do this (afaik).